# Delete pointer property in cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Upon deleting an object from the class "MyModel", the code below is attempting to delete two objects related to it via pointer attributes, one called "colors" and one called "goal".  Those objects are present in the data, but the logs indicate an "object not found" error.

Code originates from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475609/parse-cloud-delete-property-pointer).

Cloud Code:

```
function deleteMyModelPointer(myModel, pointerName, pointerClass) {
        var pointer = myModel.get(pointerName);
        if (pointer) {
            var query = new Parse.Query(pointerClass);
            return query.get(pointer).then(function(relatedObject) {
                return relatedObject.destroy();
            });
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    Parse.Cloud.beforeDelete("MyModel", function(request, response) {
        var myModel = request.object;
        deleteMyModelPointer(myModel, "colors", "ColorModel").then(function() {
            return deleteMyModelPointer(myModel , "goal", "Goal");
        }).then(function() {
            response.success();
        }, function(error) {
            response.error(error);
        });
    });
```

Log:

`v14 before_delete triggered for MyModel for user wMgAGMOPNK:
  Input: {"object":{"ACL":{"wMgAGMOPNK":{"read":true,"write":true}},"colors":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"ColorModel","objectId":"Z3gEplJ0tq"},"counter":1,"createdAt":"2015-12-10T14:06:19.630Z","createdAtLocally":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2015-12-10T14:06:18.825Z"},"deletedLocally":false,"goal":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Goal","objectId":"BkruZqhyJ7"},"lastModifiedAt":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2015-12-10T14:06:24.270Z"},"objectId":"LuobH2P8iz","resetValue":0,"stepBy":1,"title":"Ggggggg","updatedAt":"2015-12-10T14:06:24.670Z","user":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"wMgAGMOPNK"}}}
  Result: {"code":101,"message":"Object not found."}`

But both pointers are still there both from the object browser and from the client. As I said the ACL is set to the logged in PFUser for all 3 objects (with read, write permissions).

Comment: The code is already simple (and beautiful :-) ). There's only one way forward: we have to get our hands dirty. Add logs at every step, especially at the point of destroy. Comment out the destroy till we know what's happening. Post logs here.  (I bet you won't need to because you'll figure it out before its time to paste)

Comment: hey man, yeah ;) Will do. brb :P

Comment: Terribly sorry about this.  I took a second look, too.  And the code plainly misunderstands the need, which is to delete an object related by a pointer attribute (not an object id string).  Please review my answer below.  If its correct, I'll go back and correct the original.

Comment: I guess yeah, it logs the id: `{"objectId":"j1eyp5GdR3"}` Will try your answer and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the OP code is written for an objectId property, not a pointer.  With an objectId in hand, the correct action is a `query.get()` to get the related object, but for a pointer, one needs only to `fetch` the pointer (and doesn't need to know its class).

```
function deleteMyModelPointer(myModel, pointerName) {
    var pointer = myModel.get(pointerName);
    if (pointer) {
        return pointer.fetch().then(function(relatedObject) {
            return relatedObject.destroy();
        });
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Caller side can remain the same, just drop the third parameter.

Comment: redemption!  sorry again for the head-fake.  i'll fix the original answer to offer both alternatives for future readers.